# Where to find code that generates ID names in the HTML pages in a GitHub page Jekyll theme

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I see that the markdown headings have the headings as ID with spaces replaced with dashes in the generated HTML files.

I want to tinker with the code that is responsible for this so I can change the rules and replace some characters with some other characters. But I cannot seem to find where this code is.

Please help in finding the source files, for example, in this theme: https://github.com/pages-themes/minimal

Answer (score 0):

This is more a feature provided par Jekyll itself, more precisely by [**`gettalong/kramdown`**](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown), a fast, pure Ruby Markdown superset converter used by Jenkins.

See for instance in [`lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/header.rb`#`def parse_header_contents`](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/bd678ecb59f70778fdb3b08bdcd39e2ab7379b45/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/header.rb#L44-L49).